# Azure VPN to on-premises cannot connect SQL Server from azure web app

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, azure, azure-web-app-service

We have setup our VPN connection in Azure to our on-premises database, the connect is working with no problems.  I have written a MVC app that tries to connect to our on-premise database in SQL Server and am getting the following error:

> **System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904)**: A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to
>   SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify
>   that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to
>   allow remote connections.

The connection string I am using is:

```
name="productdbConnectionString" connectionString="Data Source=172.16.x.xx,1433;Initial Catalog=productdb;User Id=poppy;Password=poppyxxxxx" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"
```

I have opened TCP and named pipes and I am using port 1433 in the connection string so am a bit confused why I cannot access the database?

Comment: where's the app hosted?

Comment: Hi the app is hosted in azure, so we have the sql database hosted on premise and app hosted in Azure

Comment: no i mean, is it a webapp or just a service in a vm or what?

Comment: From the kudu console can you do tcping youripadress 1433 and see if you can communicate from azure vpn.

Comment: Just in case this point was overlooked - for a App Service 'Web App' VNET integration is available only in the Standard and Premium plans. Check this link for more info - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/azure/app-service-web/app-service-app-service-environment-network-architecture-overview

Comment: Hi it is a web app I thought if you have a VNET setup that connects your on-premise network to Azure then you can just reference any databases on premise from your azure web app?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We could connect the web app to local on-premises SQL Server database using the Hybrid Connection feature. Please refer to [this documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-web/web-sites-hybrid-connection-connect-on-premises-sql-server) that explained how to connect to on-premises SQL Server from a web app in Azure App Service using Hybrid Connections.

Comment: Hi Fred,  Looks like a good article I will try it out.  Are there any other methods of connecting an azure web app to on-premise sql server?